# Limit of a Riemann sum of $f(x)=\int_0^5(x^2 - 2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

Using the formula:
$$lim_{n\to∞}\sum_{i=0}^n f(xi)(\Delta x) $$

where $$f(x)=\int_0^5(x^2 - 2)$$ $$ \Delta x  = {b-a\over n} $$ $$xi = a - i \Delta x $$

$\Delta x  = {5\over n} $ and $xi = {5i\over n}$

I simplify to $$lim_{n\to∞}\sum_{i=0}^n{125i^2 - 10n^2\over n^3}$$

but I'm not sure where to proceed from here, as $i$ cannot be factored out of the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me start by saying that you should always use $i=1$ as your first index under the sum, not $i=0$. 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n{125i^2 - 10n^2\over n^3}\\
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(\frac{125i^2}{n^3}-\frac{10n^2}{n^3}\bigg) \\
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{125i^2}{n^3}-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{10}{n} \\
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{125}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2-\frac{10}{n}*n \\
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{125}{n^3}\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bigg) -10\\
=\frac{250}{6}-10\\
=\frac{190}{6}\\
=\frac{95}{3}$$

We can confirm that this is the correct answer by evaluating the integral directly. Indeed, $\int_0^5(x^2-2)dx = [x^3/3-2x]_0^5 = 125/3-10 = \frac{95}{3}$